# Using Normal distribution for a random sample.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The weights of a group of people are distributed on a normal curve with $\mu = 172$, $\sigma = 30$. What is the probability that the average weight of a sample of $9$ people is less than $177$?

> My attempt:

Define $X_A = \frac{X_1+X_2+X_3+X_...+X_9}{9}$, where $X_i$ are random variables representing the weights of each man.

Then $E[X_A] = 172$, and $Var[X_A] = \frac{30^2}{9}$.

Then $Z = \frac{X_A-172}{10} $,

The answer is the area to the left of $0.5$ in the standard normal curve, which is $0.6915$ (from a table). Is this right?

Comment: Yes assuming your table reading is correct

Comment: @John Doe the question had the hint "dont forget when stardardizing that $\sigma_x = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. Do you know what that could be reffering to?

Comment: When you worked out that the variance is $\frac{30^2}9$, you were essentially showing $(\sigma_x)^2=\frac{\sigma^2}n$, which is what they were referring to - that is how to get the variance of the distribution of $X_A$, the mean of a sample of size $n$

Comment: Just checking: If $\bar X_9$ denotes the mean of a sample of $n = 9$ of these people, then $E(\bar X_9) = 172$ and $SD(\bar X_9) = 30/\sqrt{9} = 10.$ Then in R statistical software `pnorm(177, 172, 10)` returns 0.6914625
.

Answer (score 1):

It equals the confidence level of a one-tailed test.